# Finding the minimum value of function ${27^6}$ +$\frac{1}{(^2−^2−^2+2)}$

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

When I put this function in GeoGebra calculator suite, I am getting the minimum value 4 but when I tried to solve, the minimum value I'm getting is different:

**My attempt:**

${27^6}$ +$\frac{1}{(^2−^2−^2+2)}$ can be written as ${27a^6}$+$\frac{1}{a^2-(b-c)^2}$

**i.e. ${27a^6}$+$\frac{1}{(a+b-c)(a-b+c)}$**

Observing, we know that, the minimum occurs at **b=c**.

so, the function gets reduced to **${27a^6}$+$\frac{1}{a^2}$**

Using ***AM-GM*** inequality, we get,

$\frac{{27a^8}+1}{2{a^2}}$ ≥ √(${27a^4}$)

or, ${27a^8}$+1 ≥ 6√3 ${a^4}$

or, ${27a^8}$-6√3 ${a^4}$+1 ≥ 0

or,${(3√3 {a^4}-1)^2}$ ≥ 0

or, ${a^4}$ ≥ $\frac{1}{3√3}$

**∴ ${a^2}$ ≥ $\frac{1}{√(3√3)}$**

Now, substituting the value of ${a^2}$ to the original equation, we get,

${27a^6}$+$\frac{1}{a^2}$ = ${{(3a^2)}^3}$ + $\frac{1}{a^2}$

≥($\frac{3}{√(3√3)})^3$ + √(3√3)

≥ 2*${3^\frac{3}{4}}$

**≥4.559014113909555283987126503927272012380640693323861911667731922**

**∴${27a^6}$+$\frac{1}{a^2}$ ≥4.6**

This implies that the minimum value of the function is 4.6 while it is 4. How? Please point out my error and also suggest your ways to solve this.
[GEOGEBRA GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYrWP.png)

Comment: Your approach is not making sense. ,(3√3a^4-1)^2 ≥ 0 is true for all $a$. It does not imply , a^4≥ 1/(3 √3).

Comment: If you wanted to apply AM-GM, you should write it as $ 27a^6 + 1/(3a^2) + 1/(3a^2) + 1/(3a^2) \geq 4$ with equality when $27a^6 = 1/(3a^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to minimize the function $$f(a) = 27a^6 + \frac{1}{a^2}$$
with respect to $a$. For that, you can simply take the first derivative and equate it to $0$.

Following these steps, you first get that $$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial a} = 162a^5-\frac{2}{a^3}.$$ From there, it follows that $$ a^* = \left(\frac{1}{81}\right)^\frac{1}{8}=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{2}.$$

Then, substituting $a^* $ in $f(a)$, you get $$f(a^*) = \frac{27}{3^3} + 3 = 4.$$

To make sure that it corresponds to the minimum, you can take the second derivative and check that it is positive. If you do so, you get that $$\frac{\partial^2 f(a)}{\partial a^2} = 810 a^4+\frac{5}{a^4},$$ which is indeed positive for any value of $a$, thus concluding the proof.

Answer (score 1):

AM-GM generally works best when you get a constant on the other side

$$
{1\over 4}(27a^6+{1\over 3a^2}+{1\over 3a^2}+{1\over 3a^2})\ge\sqrt[4]{1}
$$

So $$27a^6+{1\over a^2}\ge4$$

Comment: please explain your steps. how did you divide and took fourth root of 1

Comment: Oh I wrote $1\over x^2$ as $3\over3x^2$ then normal AM-GM for 4 terms so that I can cancel $x^6$ in GM

Comment: Can you please explain the steps clearly I am not able to understand.

Comment: I understood now thanks